# JavaScript API for getting trusted root CAs in a browser

Tags: javascript, browser, certificate

Is there a way to get the trusted root certificates by the browser in JavaScript?

Comment: That would probably be a huge security risk

Comment: Why? The public certificates are not exactly secret.

Comment: If the browser uses a non-public CA (like the ones used by orgs for their intranets, etc.) then you could identify browsers belonging to that organization. Granted "huge" was an exaggeration on my part, but it's a risk non the less.

Comment: Even so you could divide it between 'browser supplied' and 'user' CAs and make the API so that if you also want to get custom CAs then the user must explicitly consent.

Comment: You make a good point. It would still be vulnerable if IT made a custom installer and included their CA in the list of browser-supplied ones. I want to guard against this very scenario, which is how I found your question. Have you found an answer by the way?

Comment: That seems unwise, an update could wipe the custom CA maybe? I'm not well versed enough on browser handling of CAs though.
Did not find an answer, certainly no cross browser compatible way that I can see.

Comment: I've also noticed that whereas my browser shows pages as trusted that I use with my own root CA, the Javascript doesn't work and give certificat errors.